# Cast a class instance to a subclass

Tags: python, class, subclass, boto

I'm using [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) to manage some [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances. It provides an Instance class. I'd like to subclass it to meet my particular needs. Since boto provides a query interface to get your instances, I need something to convert between classes. This solution seems to work, but changing the class attribute seems dodgy. Is there a better way?

```
from boto.ec2.instance import Instance as _Instance

class Instance(_Instance):
    @classmethod
    def from_instance(cls, instance):
        instance.__class__ = cls
        # set other attributes that this subclass cares about
        return instance
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't subclass and cast.  I don't think casting is ever a good policy.

Instead, consider a Wrapper or Façade.

```
class MyThing( object ):
    def __init__( self, theInstance ):
        self.ec2_instance = theInstance
```

Now, you can subclass `MyThing` as much as you want and you shouldn't need to be casting your `boto.ec2.instance.Instance` at all.  It remains as a more-or-less opaque element in your object.

Comment: The class I'd like to subclass is much more complex than the additions I'm making (really just a few attributes). To expose all the functionality in the wrapped class, I'd need a lot of wrapped functions/properties. I understand the composition v. inheritance issue, but going the composition route seems like more trouble than it's worth in this case.

Comment: @iconoplast:  "I'd need a lot of wrapped functions/properties".  Why?  The instance is always named `myThing.ec2_instance`.  Why can't you call the EC2 instance properties and methods directly?  What else is going on?

Comment: I guess you're right. I was just trying to be clever about it.